Display array data in Table using Angular 13
I have JSON in below format.
[
  {
    "group": "A",
    "teams": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "France"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Portugual"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "B",
    "teams": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "France"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Portugual"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group": "C",
    "teams": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "France"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Portugual"
      }
    ]
  }
]


I want display above JSON in below table.

I tried with below.
this.props = this.input.map((x: any) => x.group);
this.output = this.input.reduce(
  (acc: { name: string; [key: string]: any }[], cur: any) => {
    for (let team of cur.teams) {
      let obj: { name: string; [key: string]: any } = { name: team.name };
      for (let prop of this.props) {
        obj[prop] = prop === cur.group ? team.id : undefined;
      }
      acc.push(obj);
    }
    return acc;
  },
  [] as { name: string; [key: string]: any }[]
);


HTML:
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <ng-container ngFor="let prop of props">
        <th>{{prop}}</th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ngFor="let row of output">
      <td>{{row.name}}</td>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let prop of props">
        <th>{{row[prop]??'NA'}}</th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


Hey, can you please state what's the problem then and how does it behave in the template?

It looks like below image table.
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/DhgWg.png

We need to loop through the rows, we check if the team is already present in the output array, if not we push it into the array, if the row found, we get the index and update the new group value to the found element!
Full explanation in code below with working example!
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

const data = [
  {
    group: 'A',
    teams: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'France',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Portugual',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    group: 'B',
    teams: [
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'France',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Portugual',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    group: 'C',
    teams: [
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'France',
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Portugual',
      },
    ],
  },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  styles: [
    `
  table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
  `,
  ],
  template: `
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns">
            <th>{{column}}</th>
          </ng-container>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns">
          <td>{{row[column]}}</td>
          </ng-container>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  columns: Array<any> = [];
  rows: Array<any> = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    // get the keys of the array using map, here it is group, then add a first default
     // column for `Name` to be displayed
    this.columns = ['Name', ...data.map((x) => x.group)];
    // create temporary output array to store the data
    const output: Array<any> = [];
    // loop through the data object for each group 
    data.forEach((groupRow: any) => {
      // loop through the teams under a group
      groupRow.teams.forEach((row: any) => {
        // check if the team name already exists in the array
        const foundIndex = output.findIndex(
          (item: any) => item.Name === row.name
        );
        // check if the index is found, if not it will be -1
        if (foundIndex > -1) {
          // row already exists, so update the new value with the group name
          // as a new property we will loop through this and show in UI
          output[foundIndex][groupRow.group] = row.id;
        } else {
          // if the row does not exist create a new row with the current team 
          // row group count!
          output.push({
            Name: row.name,
            [groupRow.group]: row.id,
          });
        }
      });
    });
    // after looping assign to html table array for running in ngFor!
    this.rows = output;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
